# Flash inverted mask

Tags: flash, mask

I've been looking for a simple way to invert a mask in flash. Its just amazing how it doesn't have this feature.

I just really need to paint shape and whatever is below (in layers) wont show up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

To create an inverted mask in code do the following

```
private function createInvertedMask(mcToBeMasked:MovieClip):void {

        mcToBeMasked.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
        var invertedMask:Sprite = new Sprite();
        invertedMask.graphics.beginFill(0x0, 1);
        invertedMask.graphics.drawRect(640, 395, 630, 395);
        invertedMask.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;
        mcToBeMasked.addChild(invertedMask);
    }
```

To create an inverted mask in the Flash Professional IDE 
Choose the properties panel of the image you want masked, select "Display" -> "Blending" -> "Layer"
Then select your mask, and choose "Display -> "Blending" -> "Erase"
You'll see something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: Remember for this to work inside a movie clip (i.e. you have created an inverted animated mask movie clip that will erase itself etc); the movie clip in which it is embedded MUST BE SET TO BLENDMODE: LAYER ALSO otherwise the overall effect will be ignored - hope this helps!