# How do you create an inverse mask using AS2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, mask, masking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash inverted mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231587/flash-inverted-mask)

So here's the mask:

```
imageMC.setMask(maskMC);
```

This displays the masked area, and nothing outside of it. What I need to do is the opposite; to display only the unmasked area. I need to do this dynamically with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT:

Try using the `blendMode` method:

```
// `mainMC` and `maskMC` are MovieClip objects in the FLA library.

this.attachMovie("mainMC", "main", 10);
main.attachMovie("maskMC", "punchout", 11);

main1.cacheAsBitmap = true;
main.punchout.cacheAsBitmap = true;

main.blendMode = "layer";
main.punchout.blendMode = "erase";
```